# jquery UI sortable - allow drag of image embedded in sortable div to result in start of div sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Sorry, I really have no idea how to phrase this, so apologies for the long title.  I have a table column filled with divs that are sortable (using the jquery ui sortable plugin).  Each of those divs has an image child.  Currently, when I attempt to drag the div by clicking on the image portion of the div, the div does not drag.  Obviously, I want to div to drag when I click on the image (or any portion of the div).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, I made this it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/C6JZ2/

Comment: In Chrome 8 it doesn't. You begin dragging an image and it looks bad (although it is still functional)

Comment: exactly - I'm using Chrome as well.  I figured the best way to fix this would be to somehow capture the event that is causing the image to start dragging and, instead, trigger an event that will cause the parent div to start dragging instead.  Any idea how to do this?

Comment: well that may have been a handy point to have included in the question...maybe next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:
If you are doing something like `$('#thelist').sortable();`, do the following too:

```
$('#thelist img').mousedown(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

This will prevent normal behaviour on all the images inside the list (which is, at least on Chrome and Firefox, to start dragging the image).

Comment: I realized this about an hour after I posted.  I ran into another problem though, but that's for another posting.